# How did Holika "trick" Prahlad into the pyre?

Tags: vishnu, asuras, festivals, narasimha, prahlada

Many retellings of the Holika Dahan mythology (including from [sources one might think were authoritative](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/events/when-is-holika-dahan-2024-date-time-story-history-significance-and-all-you-need-to-know-about-holika-dahan/articleshow/108673060.cms)) mention that Holika "tricked" her nephew Prahlad into sitting in her lap while she entered the burning pyre.

In what way did she "trick" him? Are there any mentions in sacred texts of deception being used to draw him into the fire?